# Using Openpyxl to pull data, by row then column

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I want to pull data from an excel file in chucks. I need to first group the data into rows and then assign tasks based on which column the cells fall into.

For instance, the first column is "job_name" and the second one is "start_time". I need the output for each row to be something along the lines of:

```
    The Job Name is "job name" and it's start time is "start time"
```

When researching this on Openpyxl's site I found the following code to start with. Not sure if this is the best path to go down:

```
    from openpyxl import load_workbook


    wb = load_workbook(filename='JobInventory.xlsx')
    ws = wb['Jobs']

    for row in ws.rows:
        for cell in row:
            #????? Now what?
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer to your question is:

`"The Job Name is {0} and it's start time is {1}".format(row[0], row[1])`

But I think you need to rethink the question. You may want to use some kind of auxiliary dictionary that will make getting and checking particular cells in a row easier.

Comment: I am not opposed to rethinking the question. And I am open to auxiliary dictionaries. But what dictionaries would be useful in this case?